# Remote connection to MySQL still not working tried all the usual advice

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I've been battling this one for a couple of days now, I've tried everything mentioned in the various other posts on this issue but I'm no closer to a solution.

I've confirmed that the correct firewall rules are in place to allow the connection.

I've checked the my.ini file
Interestingly here there were NO 'bind-address' or 'skip-networking' statements.
It's possible the poeple who originally configured the server had deleted these instead of commenting them out.

I ran the MySQL Grant All command for the user specifying the remote ip address. IE:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'myremoteIP' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The command would only accept a hashed code for the password so I had to copy it from the existing grant, I'd assume this is not an issue.

As far as I can find this should be everything I need to do but it still won't connect. Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
Bit more info on this. When I run a

```
netstat -ano
```

It only shows 3306 listening on 127.0.0.1
I would have thought that as there is no bind-address in my cfg file it should be listening on 0.0.0.0??

So I think my question really should be:
If bind-address is NOT set in the my.ini file where else might it be set?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please add also what you have tried.

Comment: When connecting via MySQL Admin tool I get the error:

MySQL Error 2003
Can't connect to MySQL Server on xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: I've also tried to check the settings in the MySQL Admin console locally.
The disable networking box is unticked and the TCP port is set. Other than that I don't see any other relevant settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it!

Turns out some 'clever' person had changed the option file to read from another location. Found the file with bind-address set to 127.0.0.1, commented the bind-address out, now it works like a charm :)

Thanks to those who had a crack at helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following things:

1) On RedHat/CentOS instances disable or edit [SELinux](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) ( setenforce 0 )

2) In the firewall open up connections on port 3306 ( [iptables](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) )

3) Try telnet'ing on this port from a remote machine

GL

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I checked and checked again on the firewall. Still can't telnet on 3306 from the remote network in question.
I can however telnet on 3306 from another remote server, which had in the past been set so its MySQL DB would push to the DB in question.

In fact I can connect remotely from one to the other but not from anywhere else.

Is there somewhere else where the bind address or a similar setting may exist?

I'm sure this is an issue of needing to specify allowed addresses for remote connection but I can't find where the current addresses have been specified.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf  then under bind address change value to 0.0.0.0 save and then restart mysql